# Cannot save table to .mdf database?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework

I created a database (.mdf) for my MVC application and whenever I add a table to the database and want to save it, it keeps prompting me to save it as a .sql file somewhere on my computer. I watched several tutorials on youtube on how to add a database to MVC application and in every video the video creator presses CTRL+S and then it prompts him to enter table name. In my case, I get this: http://prntscr.com/c8i56g

How am I supposed to save the table inside the database?

Comment: Please note that the [model-view-controller] tag is for questions about the pattern. For this question you should use [asp.net-mvc] tag.

Comment: did you try *F5* (for execute the query) button before *CTRL+S* ?

Comment: It's just asking you to save the .sql file containing the script before executing it. Save and then execute.

Answer (score 3):

Please try updating the database rather than saving it. Option to *update* is on the left top corner of the designer window for the table. Hope this helps.